# ¿Por qué sólo se carga el encabezado de mi página web desarrollado con Django?

Tags: html, html5, django, aplicación-web

Intenté crear una página web muy simple con un `base.html` y `home.html` pero sólo lo que se pone en base.html parece ser mostrado:

```
{% extends "todo/base.html" %}

<body>

    <!-- Header -->
    <header class="intro-header">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="intro-message">
          <h1>ScentMate</h1>
          <h2>Le parfumeur personnel</h2>
          <h5>Prêt à trouver le prochain parfum ? <br> Voici trois façons de trouver le parfum qui vous convient le mieux</h5>
          <hr class="intro-divider">
          <ul class="list-inline intro-social-buttons">
            <li class="list-inline-item">
              <a href="/quiz" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg">
                <span class="network-name">Take a quiz</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="list-inline-item">
              <a href="/predict" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg">
                <span class="network-name">Find similar</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="list-inline-item">
              <a href="/signin" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg">
                <span class="network-name">  Sign in   </span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <section class="content-section-a" id="about">

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-5 ml-auto">
            <hr class="section-heading-spacer">
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <h2 class="section-heading">Personalized recommendations<br>Machine learning backed up</h2>
            <p class="lead">No need to do research and try out everything at beauty stores.
              We believe there's an easier way for you to find your best match.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-5 mr-auto">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/ipad.png" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    </section>

    <section class="content-section-b">

      <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-5 mr-auto order-lg-2">
            <hr class="section-heading-spacer">
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <h2 class="section-heading">The more ratings you give<br>The better we know you</h2>
            <p class="lead">Register and rate 5 perfumes you have tried.
              You'll be surprised that we know you too well.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-5 ml-auto order-lg-1">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/dog.png" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->

    </section>
    <!-- /.content-section-b -->

    <section class="content-section-a">

      <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-5 ml-auto">
            <hr class="section-heading-spacer">
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <h2 class="section-heading">Explore the world of<br>Fine fragrances</h2>
            <p class="lead">The idea comes from our love and passion for fragrances.
              Our goal is to select best fragrances just for you...</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-5 mr-auto ">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/phones.png" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->

    </section>
    <!-- /.content-section-a -->

    <aside class="banner" id=contact>

      <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6 my-auto">
            <h2>Connect to Antoine Coppin:</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 my-auto">
            <ul class="list-inline banner-social-buttons">
            </li>
            <li class="list-inline-item">
              <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/antoine-c-261029b9/" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg">
                <i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-fw"></i>
                <span class="network-name">Linkedin</span>
              </a>
            </li>
              <li class="list-inline-item">
                <a href="https://github.com/antoinecomp" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg">
                  <i class="fa fa-github fa-fw"></i>
                  <span class="network-name">Github</span>
                </a>
              <li class="list-inline-item">
                <a href="https://twitter.com/KellyYuweiPeng" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg">
                  <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i>
                  <span class="network-name">Twitter</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->

    </aside>
    <!-- /.banner -->

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="list-inline">
          <li class="list-inline-item">
            <a href="/">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="footer-menu-divider list-inline-item">&sdot;</li>
          <li class="list-inline-item">
            <a href="#about">About ScentMate</a>
          </li>
          <li class="footer-menu-divider list-inline-item">&sdot;</li>
          <li class="list-inline-item">
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <p class="copyright text-muted small">Copyright &copy; ScentMate 2020. All Rights Reserved</p>
      </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="static/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/vendor/popper/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </body>
```

Aqui esta `base.html`:

```
{% load static %}

<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>ScentMate Perfume Recommender</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="static/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
    <link href="static/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cormorant:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allura" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alex+Brush" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

      <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ScentMate</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/signin">Sign In</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About ScentMate</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>     

</html>
```

Pero me devuelve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De hecho, sólo lo que se pone en base.html parece ser mostrado ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es porque para usar el base.html necesitas tenerlos en bloques asi tu codigo se prodra reutilizar ejemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>titulo</title>
</head>

<body>
    {% block content %}
    <!-- el contenido -->
    {% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

Este seria tu base.html y para usarlo en otro template como home.html seria:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<!-- el contenido de tu template -->
{% endblock %}
```